# Django migrate error: formisoformat argument must be string

Tags: python, django, string, typeerror, migrate

I would really need help to understand this error I get in Django that suddenly appeared after I added a bunch of objects to a models.Model class. This error persists even when I comment out all the new objects that might have provoked the error.

The code I modified is :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Band(models.Model):
    class Genre(models.TextChoices):
        Anime_music_vid= "AMV"
        Game_music_vid="GMV"
        Anime_sound_music_video="ASMV"

    name = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
genre=models.fields.CharField(choices=Genre.choices,max_length=5)
    channel = models.fields.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    publication_date = models.fields.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    creator= models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    link=models.fields.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Before the modification "name" was the only object of the class.

This error is a bunch of Tracebacks and at last it tells that there is a "TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str " in this line: return datetime.date.fromisoformat(value)
in dateparse.py file.

I've been looking for a solution for a few days now but can't seem to find any, I don't fully understand the functioning of django yet so it would be really great if anyone could tell me how to get through this.

Thanks for your time.

[image: This is a screenshot of the error I get after trying to migrate my migrations.]

Comment: Please post the model

Comment: Does `publication_date` already exist in your DB when you try to migrate `listings.0002`?

Comment: I have no idea but it wasn't the first migration I tried to make but since I added more objects it failed. It asked me to enter certain fields and I entered them but then pythin manage.py migrate would give me these errors

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, to correct it, I reset migrations.

1. You have to remove the all migrations files within your project

Go through each of your projects apps migration folder and remove everything inside, except the **init**.py file.

Or if you are using a unix-like OS you can run the following script (inside your project dir):

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

2. Create the initial migrations and generate the database schema:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Doing command you posted here you will delete Django's migrations that wont generate again with makemigrations, if you have your venv inside project dir which is common project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't answer OP's question, but for me I had a typo:

```
null=True,
default=True,
```

when it should be

```
null=True,
default=None,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you. Because I got the same problem but that helped me.

1. You need to add this codes before deleting the the class model so that you keep your db file.

```
#models.py 

import datetime
ISO_date = "2021-12-18"
default_date= datetime.date.fromisoformat(ISO_date)
```

2. Then in the **model class** set **default=default_date**

```
class Mymodel(model.Model):
   Publication = model.DateField(default=default_date)
```

3. Save the model and open the **migration folder** and delete all the files, folder except ****init**.py**
4. Don't touch on the **db** file. And make the migrations.

After remove the;

```
import datetime
ISO_date = "2021-12-18"
default_date= datetime.date.fromisoformat(ISO_date)
```

and
`default=default_date` ,

Again save and  make migrations.